# sql row_number reset at 0 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with the following values:

```
Value
0
1.2
1.3
1.4
0
1.2
1.3
1.4
```

From the above data, I need to sum the 2 highest number after the set is reset to 0, thus coming to the total of 2.8.

If I could get row_number() to restart every time there is a 0, that would be perfect, however it doesn't offer such functionality.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a column to order by. Can we assume an id field?

Comment: You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `PARTITION BY` clause - if you can partition your data by e.g. a `Category` fields or something like that. You cannot partition by "when the value is reset to 0" however.....

Comment: @martin yes there is an Id field

Comment: @marc_s I have no category fields to partition by unfortunately

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DECLARE @your_table TABLE (id INT,value FLOAT) 

INSERT INTO @your_table
SELECT 1,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1.2 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1.3 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,1.4 UNION ALL
SELECT 5,0 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,1.2 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,1.3 UNION ALL
SELECT 8,1.4


;WITH T AS
(
SELECT 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY id)-
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id ) AS Grp
,id,value
FROM @your_table
), T2 AS
(
SELECT MAX(value) AS value
FROM T
WHERE value<>0
GROUP BY Grp)
SELECT SUM(value)
FROM T2
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, have you tried using RANK or DENSE_RANK with a PARTITION BY clause?

Okay, I arrived at the same solution as @Martin and I do admit @marc_s that there's nothing simple about this. And I wasn't smart enough to figure out the relation between the two row_number groups and that subtracting them results in this table.

```
id value row_number
1  0.0    0
2  1.2   -1
3  1.3   -1
4  1.4   -1
5  0.0   -3
6  1.2   -2
7  1.3   -2
8  1.4   -2
```

From here I think it's obvious what to do next. Ignore the zeroes, group by the row_number use the max aggregate and voilá!

Comment: Well, I'm trying to be creative here, how otherwise could the query work? If there's nothing to order by initially to create the row numbers this can't possible work.

Comment: +1 for your creativity - but that's the problem - I don't see any "nice'n'easy" way either, if there's no partition available....